# Twitch Api: How can I know that stream was finished?

Tags: api, twitch

I have a stream url like `https://www.twitch.tv/streams/26114851120/channel/31809543`. Stream is online and I need to catch moment when stream will be finished.

I researched twitch api documentation and didn't find any events. The first thought was to send requests every several minutes and when stream going online - handle this. It was a little delay, but it isn't critical.

But there are many streams that I must track and I scare that twitch can block me for this.

Are there any other ways to catch stream's finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### As best I can tell there's no way to directly listen for a stream going online or offline, but you can still monitor a large number of streams in spite of that.

There are a fair number of Q&A on the official Twitch developer site wanting this functionality, but all of them I could find are answered with the same "it's not currently possible."

Keep in mind that you can check the status of multiple channels simultaneously (**up to 100 per request**) using a comma separated list and the `limit` query parameter:  [Get-Live-Streams](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/streams/#get-live-streams)

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/?get-live-streams?channel=Channel1,Channel2&limit=100
```

That'll return an object containing an array of online streams (the `streams` property).

---

### Rate Limits

Twitch's official stance regarding rate limiting is a recommendation of no more than ["about 1 request per second"](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/rate-limiting-concerns/6698).  That said they don't throttle you for making several requests in immediate succession, but rather the cumulative amount.

Note that there's a [separate rate limit](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/irc/#irc-command-and-message-limits) for IRC-related actions of 20 commands/messages per 30 seconds normally or 100 per 30 if a mod.  Violating that will trigger a 30 minute lockout.

---

### API-Side Caching

API results are also [cached for 1-3 minutes](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/pre-approved-api-call-rate/8898) which reduces load on their end.  Given that, there's not much value in polling for anything more frequently than that (i.e. you should wait at least 1 minute before making the exact same request again since you'd just get the same response).

---

### You Can Still Monitor ~6000 Streams

Given the ability to check 100 streams at a time, a need to wait for at least 1 minute per request to get new results, and an approximate rate limit of 1 request per second, you can theoretically check the status of about 6000 streams continuously (assuming you're not making other requests; 100 streams per second * 60 per minute).

---

### PubSub For Monitoring Other Things

Currently the [PubSub API](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/PubSub/) doesn't have anything for monitoring stream's going online, but you may want to keep it in mind for other polling-type actions (it currently deals with things like new subscriptions or donations).

---

### Using The Embedded Player

One last thing worth noting is you *can* listen for a channel going online or offline when you're using the [Twitch Embedded Player](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/embed/#events-emitted-by-and-defined-by-the-player).

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little late to reply, but now you can look into [Twitch WebHooks](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/webhooks-reference/).

They allow you to subscribe to specific stream(s) to have Twitch notify your callback URL, when stream goes up or down.

This seems more accurate and bandwidth-saving than querying twitch yourself.